# Banach Fixed Point Problem (Existence by showing contraction)

Tags: general-topology, banach-fixed-point

**This is a question from a past exam I am trying to solve:**

Let $C([a, b]; R)$ be the space of all continuous functions on $[a, b]$, $0 < a < b$ with the metric $∥f − g∥ = \max_{a≤x≤b} |f(x) − g(x)|$.

For each $g ∈ C([a, b]; R)$, define a map by: $$F(g(x)) = \frac{3}{(b^3-a^3)} \int_{a}^{x} t^3 g(t) dt$$  $∀x ∈ [a, b]$
Prove that there is a unique fixed point of F in the space $C([a, b]; R)$ (note $(C([a, b]; R), ∥ · ∥)$ is a complete metric space).

**My attempt:**

$$||F(f(x)) - F(g(x))| = \frac{3}{2(b^3-a^3)}|\int_{a}^{x}t^3 (f(x)-g(x))dt|$$
$$ \leq \frac{3(x-a)}{2(b^3-a^3)} *\max_{a≤t≤b}|t^3 (f(x)-g(x))|$$
$$ \leq \frac{3(b-a)}{2(b^3-a^3)} * b^3 *\max_{a≤t≤b}|f(x)-g(x)| $$ 
(this is as $x \leq b$)
$$ \leq \frac{3(b-a)}{2(b^3-a^3)} * b^3 *||f-g||$$

so now I am stuck because I cant show that: 
$$0 \leq \frac{3(b-a)}{2(b^3-a^3)} * b^3 \leq 1$$

In fact I can see that it can be greater than 1.

Can someone point out my error?

**Edit**
I've fixed up some of the typos

Comment: Please verify your question ($a^4$ or $a^3$, etc). You can use:

$$|\int_a^x t^3(f(t)-g(t))dt|\leq \int_a^x t^3|f(t)-g(t)|dt\leq \int_a^x t^3\|f-g\|dt=\frac{x^4-a^4}{4}\|f-g\|$$

Comment: There is plenty of typos in this question: in the definition of $F$ you have $f$ in the RHS and $g$ in the LHS, in the definition of $F$ there is a factor $\frac{2}{b^4-a^4}$ which magically becomes $\frac{3}{2(b^3-a^3)}$ (why?!), and the variables $x,t$ seem to be arbitrarily interchangeable (while they shouldn't be).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I typed up the question from a different example than the one I had actually attempted (and I was rushed) Everything should be correct now